Tailwind column system
I made this grid system with 12 columns, the detail is that I want to modify it in a way that I don't know if it is possible. The modification consists of adding two more columns, one at the beginning and one at the end, those two columns would be 1fr. I did that part, but what I would like to do is that between column 1 (1fr) and 2 (84px) there is no gap and the same case between column 13 (84px) and 14 (1fr). I attach the code that I have so far.

@layer components {
    .desktop-grid {
        @apply  
            lg:grid
            lg:grid-cols-[1fr_repeat(12,84px)_1fr]
            lg:mx-auto
            lg:gap-x-6;
                  }
}

i tried the code above.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

What error do I have ?

The arbitrary value for grid-cols-[] is incorrect. The values should be delimited with underscores (_), not commas (,). Also, Adam Wathan, creator of Tailwind advocates avoiding @apply: 1 and 2.

ok but is not an error because works perfectly without showing errors or warnings

OK! But please do consider not uploading images of code but instead have the code in your question as formatted text instead

In CSS grids, you can't selectively have gaps between grid column tracks. You have gaps between all of them or none of them.
As a work-around, you could consider having intermediary grid column tracks that can act as gaps:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
.desktop-grid {
  @apply lg:grid
    lg:grid-cols-[1fr_repeat(11,84px_theme(gap.6))_84px_1fr]
    lg:mx-auto;
}
</style>

<div class="desktop-grid">
  <div class="col-span-2 h-10 bg-red-200"></div>
  <div class="col-start-2 col-[span_23/span_23] h-10 bg-blue-200"></div>
</div>



